# windows phone 8 emulator auto shutdown white booting

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I turn on Emulator to debug app, it show following text (no dialog) and shutdown

[image]
[image]
[image]

i've tried to reinstall SDK 8.0 but it still that error. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What version of windows are you running?

Comment: open you Hiper-V center and check for any errors for corresponding VM

Comment: no error, but i still can start windows phone 8 virtual machine here

Comment: so you can start WP VMs from Hyper-V center and they are not shutting down immediately?

Comment: yes, i try to start emulator from different project, from VS 2012 pro and express, but cannot boot emulator success

Comment: no - I mean exactly from Hyper-V Manager, not from Visual Studio. It also contains logs that can help with analysis

Comment: yes, i can start emulator from Hyper-V Manager, and it not shutting down. Where do i can get logs

Answer (score 0):

Open Hyper-V Manager and check the Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch from Virtual Switch Manager. Remove all the emulator switch and start a new instance of the emulator.